# MYSQL group by date and count first date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying a MySQL database and from columns user_id, signup_date and order_date I would like to know out of the users that signed up in week N, how many of them placed their first order in N+1, N+2, N+3...

This is my query but it is failing on the count(min() because of how it is grouped I believe.

My skills are limited so apologies if i'm way off track

I have tried grouping differently but don't really understand how i can group dates but still only count the first/earliest order date

```
SELECT 
signup_year, 
signup_week, 
COUNT(signup_date) AS "total_signups", 
order_year,
order_week,
SUM(orders) AS total_first_orders

FROM
(
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(s.signup_timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y") AS signup_date,
YEAR(s.signup_timestamp) AS signup_year,
WEEK(s.signup_timestamp) AS signup_week,
YEAR(o.order_timestamp) AS order_year,
DATE_FORMAT(o.order_timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y") AS order_date,
WEEK(o.order_timestamp) AS order_week,
COUNT(MIN(o.order_timestamp)) AS orders

FROM signups s
INNER JOIN orders o ON s.user_id = o.user_id

GROUP BY o.user_id, YEAR(o.user_id),WEEK(o.user_id)

) X
GROUP BY signup_year ASC, signup_week ASC, order_year ASC, order_week ASC
```

from columns user_id, signup_date and order_date I would like to know out of the users that signed up in week N, how many of them placed their first order in N+1, N+2, N+3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is rather harder than at first glance, because you are mixing signup dates with order dates.  For that `union all` helps.

Second, you need to enumerate the orders.  In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select year(ts) as year, week(ts) as week,
       sum(issignup) as num_signups,
       sum(order_seqnum = 1) as orders_1,
       sum(order_seqnum = 2) as orders_2,
       sum(order_seqnum = 3) as orders_3
from ((select o.order_timestamp as ts,
              row_number() over (partition by o.userid order by o.order_timestamp) as order_seqnum,
              1 as isorder, 0 as issignup
       from signups s join
            orders o 
            on s.user_id = o.user_id7
      ) union all
      (select s.signup_timestamp, null, 0 as isorder, 1 as issignup
       from signups s
      )
     ) os 
group by year(ts), week(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You culd try using a join between the subqiery for sign and order

```
    select t1.user_id, t1.y_sign, t1.m_sign, t1.w_sign, t1.num_sign, t2.w_first_ord
    from (
        select   o.user_id, year(s.signup_timestamp) y_sign, month(s.signup_timestamp) m_sign,  week(s.signup_timestamp) w_sign, count(*) num_sign
        FROM signups s
        INNER JOIN orders o ON s.user_id = o.user_id7
        group by o.user_id, week(s.signup_timestamp)
    ) t1 
    left join(

        select  o.user_id, week(min(o.order_timestamp)) w_first_ord
        FROMM orders o 
        group by  o.user_id
    ) on t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id and t1.w_sign = t2.num_sign
```